# How do I detect different OS system

Tags: python

I am making a quiz game and I want to make it so that when ever you go to test mode it will clear your screen. I want the program to be compatible with UNIX and windows. I want it to make it so that if the system is windows, it runs cls in the terminal, and if your on Linux it runs clear. I have nothing wrong with my code, I just can find what I want to do online.

Comment: Have you done any research on your own before posting this question?  I just did a very quick search and the *first* hit gives the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.name` would return `nt` if your system is Windows, and `posix` if POSIX, so you can do it like this

```py
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    os.system('cls')
else:
    os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Please don’t post answers when 1) Poster doesn’t provide evidence of trying to work out the solution on their own, and 2) when an answer already exists.